# How to Open a New Page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I've tried to research everywhere and all I get is how to open an close forms. I'm making an XAML Windows 8 C# App and I need it to display `Menu.xaml` from the click of a button in `MainPage.xaml`.

Here is the button:

```
<Button Content="Agree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,506,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="46" Width="392" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

Here is the code that was generated in `MainPage.xaml.cs` by Visual Studio when I double clicked on the button in Design Mode

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike normal WPF apps that allow you to just add user controls and windows to the screen, Marketplace apps (which I am assuming you are talking about) require you to "Navigate" between XAML pages. Here is an outline of the procedure you require http://www.markermetro.com/2011/11/technical/windows-8-metro-style-apps-implementing-navigation-with-xaml/

Here is a basic example but you should read the link

```
       void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(AboutView).FullName);
        }
```

Comment: I just want it to display the new XAML's page after clicking the button

Comment: That is exactly what this does

Comment: So the first one will close and the next one opens?

Comment: Think of your xaml pages like web pages. Your app has to navigate between them. You do this above example to navigate to the page. Then you use the goback example to goback.

Comment: @user2039764 This answer is the solution to your question. Please make sure to click the check mark so others will know this has been resolved. Thank you

Comment: @user2039764 check out [Create your first Windows Store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx), particularly "[Part 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx)" which covers navigation